# Excel - If condition only for non blanks in list containing blanks and non blanks?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel - If condition only for non blanks in list containing  blanks and non blanks?

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | app | apple |
| 2 | Orange |  |  |
| 3 | Peach | pe | pe |
| 4 | Plum |  |  |
| 5 | Grapes | gra | Grapes |
| 6 | Guava | gua | gua |

The following code I want to only work for non-blank cells.

```
=if(OR(D1=B1,D1=C1),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest an IF:

```
=IF(D1<>"",if(OR(D1=B1,D1=C1),1,0),0)
```

Or use an AND()

```
=IF(AND(D1<>"",OR(D1=B1,D1=C1)),1,0)
```

[image]
[image]